# How configure Blisk as the Default Browser in my Mac WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Currently I have Chrome as my default browser in my Mac.

I use WebStorm and I'd like that Blisk be its default browser for web dev.

Chrome as Mac default browser and Blisk as Webstorm default browser.

I already config it in WebStorm but it don't works. With any `npm start` command it opens Chrome.

This is my config:

[image: WebStorm Settings]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine, and WebStorm should use *Blisk* as its default browser - what browser is opened when you choose **Help | Help**, for example?
But these settings only work for actions performed by the IDE, they don't change your system default browser to the one configured in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers**. If your npm script starts a module that runs your system default browser, it will still be a system default browser, not the IDE one.

Comment: You are right... *Help | Help* opens _Blisk_ .
It's something about my project. Thanks